# ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper

Tags: sas

I have searched some info about this error,but it seems none match mine,may someone familiar with this error take a look.

"Code generated by a SAS macro, or submitted with a "submit selected" operation in your editor, can leave off a semicolon inadvertently." it is still abstruse for me to explore in my code by this comment.although I got this error,the outcomes is right.may someone give any advice..thanks!

```
%let cnt=500;
%let dataset=fund_sellList;
%let sclj='~/task_out_szfh/fundSale/';
%let wjm='sz_fundSale_';

%macro write_dx;
    options spool;
    data _null_;
    cur_date=put(today(),yymmdd10.);
    cur_date=compress(cur_date,'-');
    cnt=&cnt;
    retain i;
    set &dataset;
    if _n_=1 then i=cnt;
        if _n_<=i then do;
            abs_filename=&sclj.||&wjm.||cur_date||'.dat';
            abs_filename=compress(abs_filename,'');
            file anyname filevar=abs_filename encoding='utf8' nobom ls=32767 DLM='|';
                put cst_id @;
                put '@|' @;
                put cust_name @;
                put '@|' ;
        end;
    run;
%mend write_dx;

%write_dx();
```

and if I am not using macro,there is no error.

```
data _null_;
    options spool;
    cur_date=put(today(),yymmdd10.);
    cur_date=compress(cur_date,'-');
    cnt=&cnt;
    retain i;
    set &dataset;
    if _n_=1 then i=cnt;
        if _n_<=i then do;
            abs_filename=&sclj.||&wjm.||cur_date||'.dat';
            abs_filename=compress(abs_filename,'');
            file anyname filevar=abs_filename encoding='utf8' nobom ls=32767 DLM='|';
                put cst_id @;
                put '@|' @;
                put cust_name @;
                put '@|' ;
        end;
    run;
```

--------------------------------update----------------------------------
  I add % to the keyword,but still get the same error

```
%macro write_dx;
        options spool;
        data _null_;
        cur_date=put(today(),yymmdd10.);
        cur_date=compress(cur_date,'-');
        cnt=&cnt;
        retain i;
        set &dataset;
        %if _n_=1 %then i=cnt;
            %if _n_<=i %then %do;
                abs_filename=&sclj.||&wjm.||cur_date||'.dat';
                abs_filename=compress(abs_filename,'');
                file anyname filevar=abs_filename encoding='utf8' nobom ls=32767 DLM='|';
                    put cst_id @;
                    put '@|' @;
                    put cust_name @;
                    put '@|' ;
            %end;
        run;
    %mend write_dx;

    %write_dx();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you add `()` to the macro call when the macro is not designed to accept any parameters?  If you do that then the `()` are NOT processed by the macro processor and so are passed along to SAS to interpret.  That is the same error message as you would get if you submitted `();` by itself.

```
1    %macro xx ;
2    data _null_;
3     put 'Running data step in macro';
4    run;
5    %mend xx;
6    %xx();

Running data step in macro
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.02 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


6    %xx();
        -
        180
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

7    ****;
8    ();
     -
     180

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
```

But if you define it with 0 or more parameters.

```
%macro param();
generated code
%mend ;

%put |%param()|;
```

The macro processor will use the `()` and so they are not passed onto SAS to use.

```
|generated code|
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
%macro write_dx;
```

to

```
%macro write_dx();
```

When creating a macro, you have to include the `()` even if no values are passed.